# Householder reflections

Tags: matrices, transformation, reflection

Let $x=\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
2\\ 
3
\end{bmatrix}$

I want to use a Householder reflector U to keep only first element in vector x, and make everything else zero

but I'm doing something wrong...

---

$U=I-\frac{uu^T}{\beta}$

$\beta=\frac{\left \| u \right \|_2^2}{2}$

$Ux=x-u$

---

$\beta=\frac{16}{2}=8$

$u=\begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
2\\ 
3
\end{bmatrix}$

$U=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 1 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} 
-\frac{1}{8}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 4 & 6\\ 
0 & 6 & 9
\end{bmatrix}$

$U=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{3}{4}\\ 
0 &  -\frac{3}{4} & -\frac{1}{8}
\end{bmatrix}$

---

but $Ux \neq x-u$ (will not make anything zero)

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong

---

EDIT:

If
$u=\begin{bmatrix}
-3\\ 
2\\ 
3
\end{bmatrix}$

then
$uu^T=\begin{bmatrix}
     9  &  -6  &  -9 \\
    -6  &   4   &  6 \\
    -9  &   6  &   9
\end{bmatrix}$

but it's still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $u$ should be calculated as $u=x-\|x\|(1,0,0)^T$, but you mistook it as $u=x-(1,0,0)^T$.