# Householder matrix confusion

Tags: linear-algebra

I read that: If $(I-2ww^T)x=y$ and $x \neq 0$ ($w^Tw=1$) then
$$w= \dfrac{(x-y)}{\|x-y\|_2}.$$

I tested this for $x=[9,2,6]^T$ and $y=[-11,0,0]^T$ and it worked.
But for some reason for $x=[1,2,3]^T$ and $y=[1,0,0]^T$ it doesn't work... the result was $[1,-2,-3]^T$ instead of $[1,0,0]^T$.

I must be missing something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You do. Let $Q=I-2ww^T$. Then $Q$ is a real orthogonal matrix because $QQ^T=Q^2=I$. **Therefore it preserves norm**.

Comment: So 2nd example... is useless?

Comment: @user64985 How can the reflection of $x$ (about some hyperplane) be $y$ when the two vectors have different norms?

Comment: Yes, you are right... I took that example from here without thinking: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284532/householder-reflections